# Can't read application.properties of spring boot project in AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am trying to implement 1 function which access to database get information and deploy it to AWS lambda function.

```
@Service
public class TestConnection {

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String dbUrl;

public void CheckConnection() {
    try {
        System.out.println(dbUrl);
        System.out.println(this.dataSource.toString());
        System.out.println(this.dataSource.getConnection());
        System.out.println(this.dataSource.getConnection().getCatalog());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It work perfectly in my local but when I deploy to AWS lambda function by Jar file. It cant read any value from application.properties

```
START RequestId: e30a31c6-0ada-4c40-a038-9ffcd288d15f Version: $LATEST
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
null
END RequestId: e30a31c6-0ada-4c40-a038-9ffcd288d15f
REPORT RequestId: e30a31c6-0ada-4c40-a038-9ffcd288d15f  Duration: 4.95 ms
```

Thanks for helping me.

updated shade package to build jar file in POM file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you have a class which implements the Lambda handler interface?

Comment: Yes, I have already implement Lambda handler interface, but when deploy to AWS it  cannt read application.properties file.

Comment: Can you provide more of how you're working with Spring and your handler.

Comment: Yah, I am trying to deploy 1 function access to JpaRepository to fetch data from postgres database(AWS RDS). After many time debug, I found that connection load from application.properties cant be load. So I do this code for test load config from application.properties.

Comment: I also implement RequestHandler interface with my function.

Comment: It looks like the data source isn't being auto-wired. It's hard to make a suggestion without more information.

Comment: Yah, I'm sorry because my code so complex and depend on many other interface. So it difficult to copy and past all in that post, but after many time debug and research I found root error is connection from application.properties cant load when deployed to AWS Lambda. Or in the other case, maybe the ways I have built jar file is have problem. I use cmd: mvn clean package shade:shade to build jar file.  And dependency in POM file I have updated in that post, Thanks for helping me a lot!